# Comparing two dates in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a mysql database table with a column called task_end_date and task_name.

I want to select all the task_name from the table where the current date has passed task_end_date. How would i do that in mysql using an sql query.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT task_name FROM table WHERE curdate() > task_end_date
```

Note that `curdate()` as its name implies has no TIME component. If time really isn't important, then `curdate()` is the way to go, otherwise go with `now()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  x,y,z
FROM
  foo
WHERE
  task_end_date < Now()
```

Maybe you want [Curdate()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) instead of [Now()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now).